# Java Optional orElseThrow with empty collection

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm implementing a stream in which I use a collection **listOfFoo** to get ids of all items in that list and use them to get values of Bar instances.

I would like to ensure that this method will throw **ResourceNotFoundException** in case there is no items on bars list, although in the current state it checks if list bars is null and it is not, since it contains an empty list.

Could you please help me and suggest some solution?

```
List<Bar> bars = Optional.ofNullable(
           listOfFoos.stream()
           .map(Foo::getId)                                         
           .map(fooId -> service.getBars(fooId))                                            
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList()))                            
       .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(Bar.class, OBJECT_NULL));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add an `Optional.filter` for it then. You could do it as :

```
List<Bar> bars = Optional.ofNullable(
        listOfFoos.stream().map(fooId -> service.getBars(fooId))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(a -> !a.isEmpty())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(Bar.class, OBJECT_NULL));
```

Aside: By the implementation shared in the code, the list returned by the stream could not be `null`, so `Optional.ofNullable` could possibly be replaced by `Optional.of`.

Answer (score 11):

I don't really see the benefit of using `Optional`, it would be more readable without it :

```
List<Bar> bars = listOfFoos.stream()
   .map(Foo::getId)       
   .map(service::getBars)                    
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (bars.isEmpty()) {
   throw new ResourceNotFoundException(Bar.class, OBJECT_NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The book **Effective Java** mentions the following:

> Container types, including collections, maps, streams, arrays, and
>   optionals should not be wrapped in optionals. (P.252)